# Data input problem #input() not enough values to unpack in Anaconda3

Tags: python, input, valueerror, anaconda3

I currently use anaconda3. When I ran the code in anaconda below:

```
n, m = map(int, input('insert : ').split())
```

I wanted to see the result below

```
n, m = map(int, input('insert : ').split())
```

Then, I could put some datas next to the `'insert :'` message.

However, I got this error code below instead of `'insert :'` message.

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly are you placing your data?

You shouldn't place them like this:

```
n, m = map(int, input('insert : 31 41').split())
```

Otherwise it will give you the ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0).

You need to run the code as it is:

```
n, m = map(int, input('insert :').split())
```

And on your console it will "ask" you to input your data like this:

```
input: <your value (n)>  <your value (m)>
```

Make sure that when putting your values, leave a space in between the two values so Python can map the variables otherwise you'll get the same ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0).